# Can't append Button element to li parent

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to append a button into a li item with the `.appendChild` method, but it doesn't work. I also tried altering the parent's inner HTML.

```js
let inputElement = document.querySelector('#input');
let listItem = document.createElement('li');
listItem.className = 'todo-item'

let checkButton = document.createElement('button');
checkButton.className = 'checkButton' 

//? When adding the child element, it is only added after the text content is defined.
listItem.appendChild(checkButton); 
listItem.textContent = inputElement.value;
```

```html
<div class="app">
    <div class="list">
        <h1> My Todo List </h1>
        <ul class="todo-list" id="list">
            <div class="list-row">
                <li class="todo-item"><button class="checkButton"></button> Test Item </li>
            </div>
            <div class="list-row">
                <li class="todo-item"><button class="checkButton"></button> Test Item </li>
            </div>
        </ul>
    <input id="input" class="list-input" type="text" placeholder="Next I need to...">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the current result
[image: browser screen capture]

If I modify the order in which the child is appended, the button DOES show up but it's not the best result

```
//? When adding the child element, it is only added after the text content is defined.
listItem.textContent = inputElement.value;
listItem.appendChild(checkButton);
```

[image: browser screen capture v2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the *textContent* property will reset the whole *li* element, thus removes the previously added button, try with [`insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML).

> The `insertAdjacentHTML()` method of the Element interface parses the specified text as HTML or XML and inserts the resulting nodes into the DOM tree at a specified position. It does not reparse the element it is being used on, and thus it does not corrupt the existing elements inside that element.

```js
let inputElement = document.querySelector('#input');
let listItem = document.createElement('li');
listItem.className = 'todo-item'

let checkButton = document.createElement('button');
checkButton.className = 'checkButton' 

listItem.appendChild(checkButton); 
listItem.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',inputElement.value);

document.querySelector('#list').appendChild(listItem);
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="list">
      <h1> My Todo List </h1>
      <ul class="todo-list" id="list">
          <div class="list-row">
              <li class="todo-item"><button class="checkButton"></button> Test Item </li>
          </div>
          <div class="list-row">
              <li class="todo-item"><button class="checkButton"></button> Test Item </li>
          </div>
      </ul>
  <input id="input" class="list-input" type="text" placeholder="Next I need to...">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Comment: The buttons dont have text, I just tried adding text to the button after it is created but it still does not show up

Answer (score 1):

First do not be so greedy with the ";" signs ;)
This happens cause the whole thing is wrong :)
Look, This would and will work perfectly in plain html:

```
<ul>
    <li><input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other  </li>
    ....
</ul>
```

And now we do exactly the same in Javascript.

```
var ipb=document.createElement("INPUT")    //Not button ! Forget that this 
                                          // button tag 
                                         // even exists
    ipb.setAttribute("id","ibp_0");     //always a good idea
    ipb.setAttribute("name","gender"); //if its inside a form you want to use
                                      //and a must have for radio buttons *)'
    ipb.setAttribute("type","radio");// or checkbutton or input - what you 
                                    //     want for a input type
    ipb.setAttribute("value","male");

         var txt = document.createTextNode("Male");
         ipb.appendChild(txt);

     // and now you can
     LIST.appendChild(ipb); //the formaly created <UL> Node for sure
```

As you can see its the same thing like writing the html version just in a different syntax. There is no magic thing in behind which will do something for you.

The text node is not a perfect idea. I would use a label for that. Or a additional Label.
A label has a "FOR" attribute which i really suggest to use if you go that way. 
But this typing i let up to ou :) Have fun !

*) radio buttons. They know that they belong together by the name.

Comment: Would using the input type radio, allow me to remove that specific child node? I want to add a function to remove a item from the list, for now I just want them to be strike through

Comment: Try it :) if you replace type radio by type checkbox (and adjust the names) you can test it by self. i just show them cause they are the hardest to understand ones and cause your screenshot looks like. I would add a button to remove things or add additional checkbox items to mass remove. Its up to you - you design :) It is usually a good idea to look what others have designed and what you like to use.

Comment: And i would also put things like create_checkbox create input field into functions. makes it easy to reuse the code or build a nice template system. Create such things are how to say : "a not a so interesting task" ;)

Answer (score 0):

You've created the element, for `listItem` but you've never actually added it to the DOM.

You need to append or insert the `listItem` before you try to add the checkbox.

Comment: Then how *When adding the child element, it is only added after the text content is defined*?